# Prove $\neg (\;(\;\neg \; p \;\land q \;) \lor (\; \neg \; p \; \land \neg \; q)) \equiv p$ using logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am a student in a first year discrete mathematics course at university, I have found the following problem within a practice paper.

Let $p$ and $q$ be statement variables, prove that $\neg (\;(\;\neg \; p \;\land q \;) \lor (\; \neg \; p \; \land \neg \; q)) \equiv p$ using the laws of logical equivalence.

I have included my attempt below. To me, it seems correct but I have been informed that I have made an error. Could someone please be kind enough to point it out for me.

$\neg (\;(\;\neg \; p \;\land q \;) \lor (\; \neg \; p \; \land \neg \; q)) $

$\equiv \neg \; (\neg \; p \; \land \; (q \; \lor \neg \;q))$

$\equiv \neg \; (\neg \; p \; \land \; \pmb t ) $

$ \equiv \neg \; ( \; \neg \;p) $

$\equiv p$

Comment: Correct........

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that is what I thought, but I have been told that I cannot use the distributive law with the negation out the front.

Comment: In this case, use De Morgan to move it inside.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA by move it inside to you mean use De Morgan to go from $\neg (\;(\;\neg \; p \;\land q \;) \lor (\; \neg \; p \; \land \neg \; q))$ to $\neg(\neg p \land q) \land \neg(\neg  p \land \neg q)$ ?

Comment: Yes; and then use it again on each of the conjuncts.

Comment: I don't get why your professor doesn't allow using the distributive law with the negation out front. It seems fine to me. You just could make a separate expression with the negation removed first, show that to be equivalent to "not $p$", and then negate both sides of the equivalence, yielding the desired result.